# Display image in different position on the screen

Tags: java, android

I want to develop a small game in android using canvas..i want to redrew and display the image in top left, right, bottom left, right and middle...Here my sample code is

```
public class Game extends View {
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        canvas.drawBitmap(image, x, 0, paint);
    }

    // called by thread
    public void update() {
        if(x < 453)
            x++;
        else
            x=0;
    }
}
```

in ACTIVITY i call the update function through handler function and its working, but its redraw the image only in top left and right.

Actually i wanted to display like that:

1. it should be top-left
2. bottom-right
3. bottom-left
4. top-right
5. center
6. cont...

Comment: You're not changing the view' y coordinate, means it will always be drawn on the same height.

Comment: @Egor is right.make the logic for changing y coordinate plz and you will get your result.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing in this question that you can't answer without anyone's help. Just put a bit of thinking in it and you'll get the result.